# Systemd does not see /dev/disk/by-label/tmp

Tags: systemd

My systemd does not see `/dev/disk/by-label/tmp` which is to be mounted on my `/tmp`. It gets stuck waiting for the mounting service of `/tmp`. When I run a tty9-debug-shell, then all I have to do is:

```
mount /tmp
```

and the system continues booting up nicely.

`/etc/fstab` contains:

```
LABEL=tmp /tmp ext4 nofail,errors=remount-ro 0       3
```

This does not happen if I boot in rescue mode.

How can I make `systemd` just try the `mount /tmp`?

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 17.04 \n \l
$ uname -a
Linux hk 4.10.0-20-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 09:22:42 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Not sure, but are the device symlinks already present when the system boots and tries to mount local filesystems? These are created through udevd and that might not be active in rescue mode?

Comment: @ridgy How do I determine that? I can only react so fast on the tty9-debug-shell.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not an answer to your question, I have to give it that way for formatting and as it's too long for a comment.

Look at the kernel message buffer with `dmesg | less`. This shows when which service is started. In my case, I see (leaving unrelated lines):

```
[   11.946916] systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service: Installed new job systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service/start
[   11.947163] systemd[1]: systemd-udevd-kernel.socket: Installed new job systemd-udevd-kernel.socket/start 
[   11.947217] systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Installed new job systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service/start 
[   11.947232] systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Installed new job systemd-remount-fs.service/start
[   11.947255] systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Installed new job systemd-udevd.service/start
[   11.947324] systemd[1]: systemd-udev-trigger.service: Installed new job systemd-udev-trigger.service/start
[   11.948120] systemd[1]: tmp.mount: Installed new job tmp.mount/start
[   11.948498] systemd[1]: proc-fs.mount: Collecting.
[   11.948522] systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2dlabel.mount: Collecting.
.
[   14.151615] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, no debug enabled
[   14.173106] XFS (sdb1): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[   14.462102] XFS (sdb1): Ending clean mount
```

etc.

The last three entries are resulting from the `fstab`entry

```
/dev/disk/by-label/data /data   xfs defaults,nofail,noatime 0   0
```

I do not know which of the lines in `dmesg` are really important in this case. 
But it seems that the mount of `/tmp` (11.948120) takes place before `/dev/disk/by-label` is created and populated. So, if there is no special reason, you should not mount /tmp this way.

You might find out by modifying the `fstab` line to read `LABEL=tmp /mnt ext4 nofail,errors=remount-ro 0       3` and then reboot and look at the respective output of `dmesg`. And when having booted in system rescue mode, try `mount` or `df /tmp` to see where /tmp is mounted/situated. Maybe `/etc/fstab` is not used then.